# PySpark application unable to find Python when using UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

When I try to use a UDF in my local pyspark application, an error is produced saying python cannot be found.

Sample UDF I am using:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sql_func 

test_udf = sql_func.udf(lambda x: x.lower(), StringType())
df.withColumn("Sample", test_udf("SampleCol")).show(5)
```

Error message

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
22/06/30 10:49:45 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
22/06/30 10:49:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

However, this error only happens when I am evaluating a Spark UDF. I am able to convert the Spark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame and apply the same function without an issue. However, whenever I evaluate the DataFrame with a df.show() after the udf is applied it does not work.

Notes about my set up:

- Running on Windows 10
- Using Virtual environment with Python 3.9.6
- Spark 3.3

Things I have tried that did not work:

- Disabling the short cut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases
- Adding PYSPARK_PYTHON to my system environment variables

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have [`spark.pyspark.python` config](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) and/or [`PYSPARK_PYTHON` env. variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) defined for your Spark sesson?

Comment: @mazaneicha Thank you! This is what I was missing. After adding `spark.pyspark.python` config option to my SparkSession as `.config("spark.pyspark.python", "python3")` it works!